# Calling multiple JavaScript functions on a button click

Tags: javascript, function

How to call multiple functions on button click event?

Here is my button,

```
<asp:LinkButton
    ID="LbSearch"
    runat="server"
    CssClass="regular"
    onclick="LbSearch_Click"
    OnClientClick="return validateView();ShowDiv1();">
```

But my `ShowDiv1` doesn't get called...

My JavaScript functions:

```
function ShowDiv1() {
    document.getElementById("ReportDiv").style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}

function validateView() {

    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLCategory").selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "Please Select Your Category";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLCategory").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLEmpName").selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "Please Select Your Employee Name";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLEmpName").focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the `ValidateView()` function returns true I should call `ShowDiv1()`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because you're returning from the first method call, the second doesn't execute.

Try something like

```
OnClientClick="var b = validateView();ShowDiv1(); return b"
```

or reverse the situation,

```
OnClientClick="ShowDiv1();return validateView();"
```

or if there is a dependency of div1 on the validation routine.

```
OnClientClick="var b = validateView(); if (b) ShowDiv1(); return b"
```

What might be best is to **encapsulate multiple inline statements** into a mini function like so, to simplify the call:

```
// change logic to suit taste
function clicked()  {
    var b = validateView(); 
    if (b) 
        ShowDiv1()
    return b;
}
```

and then

```
OnClientClick="return clicked();"
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because, it gets returned after `validateView();;`

Use this:

```
OnClientClick="var ret = validateView();ShowDiv1(); return ret;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ....
I got it...
onClientClick="var b=validateView();if(b) var b=ShowDiv1();return b;"

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
OnClientClick="return validateView();ShowDiv1();">
```

to

```
OnClientClick="javascript: if(validateView()) ShowDiv1();">
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't getting called because you have a return statement above it.  In the following code:

```
function test(){
  return 1;
  doStuff();
}
```

doStuff() will never be called.  What I would suggest is writing a wrapper function

```
function wrapper(){
   if (validateView()){
     showDiv();
     return true;
   }
}
```

and then call the wrapper function from your `onclick` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since `return validateView();` will return a value (to the click event?), your second call `ShowDiv1();` will not get called.

You can always wrap multiple function calls in another function, i.e.

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="return display();">

function display() {
   if(validateView() && ShowDiv1()) return true;
}
```

You also might try:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="return (validateView() && ShowDiv1());">
```

Though I have no idea if that would throw an exception.

Comment: That will not throw an exception if both functions exist, the only problem is that if the `validateView` function returns true, the return statement will get the value of the second operand of the `&&` operator, and since that function doesn't return anything it will return undefined, e.g.: `true && undefined == undefined`

Comment: Would the solution be to use the || operator?

Answer (score 0):

And of course you can never call the two functions at the same time. Not any one in the world except you are working on two processors simultaneously.

The best way is to call a JavaScript parent function and in that, specify all the sequence of function you want to call. For example,

```
function ShowDiv1() {
    document.getElementById("ReportDiv").style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}

function validateView()
{
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLCategory").selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "Please Select Your Category";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLCategory").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLEmpName").selectedIndex == 0) {
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = "Please Select Your Employee Name";
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DLEmpName").focus();
        return false;
    }
    ShowDiv1();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are more than 2 js function then following two ways can also be implemented:

1. if you have more than two functions you can group them in if condition

   OR
2. you can write two different if conditions.

1  OnClientClick="var b = validateView(); if (b) ShowDiv1(); if(b) testfunction();  return b">

OR

2 OnClientClick="var b = validateView(); if(b) 
{

ShowDiv1();

testfunction();

} return b">

Answer (score 0):

At times it gives syntax error that "return is not a function" so in that case just remove return and it will work fine :) as shown below

```
OnClientClick="var b = validateView(); if(b) var b = ShowDiv1(); b;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  OnClientClick ="showDiv()"
   OnClick="btnImport_Click" Text="Upload" ></asp:Button>
```

Comment: Could you read this and improve on this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

```
btnSAVE.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "var b = DropDownValidate('" + drp_compcode.ClientID + "') ;if (b) b=DropDownValidate('" + drp_divcode.ClientID + "');return b");
```