# onclick attribute on image to change image and to call a function

Tags: html, events

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function functionCall(){
...
}
</script>
```

---

```
<input type="image" src="uri1.png" onclick="this.src='uri2.png'"/>
```

**this works for changing the image for onclick event**

```
<input type="image" src="uri1.png" onclick="functionCall"/>
```

**this works for calling a function**

> how do i make both function call and image change to occur for same onclick.

Comment: But why are you doing both things separately. Just change the img source in that function call!!!

Comment: Here is a related answer!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414500/calling-multiple-javascript-functions-on-a-button-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple actions by separating with ;

`onclick="this.src='uri2.png'; functionCall()"`